# Drupal 7 - Change specific text based on user's country?

Tags: 7

I'm new to drupal. I'm building a contest site where I display the cash prize for the winner on the front page. I want to change the prize amount and the currency sign based on the user's country.

**For Example :**
If a person is from Europe then show £50 and for the rest show $25.

Is there a module for that ? or Can I hard-code that in the page--front.tpl.php ? (I know we shouldn't hard-code in template files but this is the simplest solution I have so far)

**Note :** I don't need currency conversion or exchange rates, I just want to change the text based on the user's country.

Thanks in advance.